# WSL connect to remote server and use X server from windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

We have our company server, where we connect using `ssh` and private key. There we have oracle wallet manager (`owm`), but it can only be run using Xserver. If I setup putty in windows, allow x11 forwarding with address `localhost:0.0`, it works fine. But I was trying to accomplish that through wsl. What I was able to do, is that I can ping now between windows and wsl, I can connect to our working server using `ssh <username>@<servername> -p 22 -i /path_to_certificate/certificate_name.pem`, but from there, I am stuck.

I was trying to set `DISPLAY` variable to windows machine IP `address:0.0`, to wsl address and all combinations I could try, but still nothing. I have enabled X11 forwarding in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Does anyone have Idea, if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is responsible for the **server** side, and it only specifies whether X11 forwarding is permitted on the server (and would only have effect on the destination server, the one you `ssh` to).

But you should also enable it on the client side on your WSL via `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. You need to add the following to allow X11 forwarding by default:

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

You can also add the `-X` flag to your `ssh` command (Enables X11 forwarding) if you don't want to allow this by default. You can try this first as a test, and if it works you can change your `ssh_config`.

Don't forget to set your `DISPLAY` to `localhost:0.0` on your WSL client before performing the `ssh`.